# Materialized view - Viewing while refresh happens

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

Is it possible to select and view the existing data from materialized view while a complete refresh happens?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on whether the refresh is atomic or not.

In an atomic refresh, Oracle behind the scenes will delete the existing data and re-insert the results.  That takes longer but queries that start before the refresh finishes will see the old data.  In a non-atomic refresh, Oracle behind the scenes will truncate the existing data and re-insert.  That makes for a faster refresh but it means that the materialized view will be empty during the refresh.

If you are using [dbms_mview.refresh](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_mview.htm#i997194), atomic is the default refresh method.

Comment: How do you know this much and where one like me can find this kind of information.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - Lots of experience making mistakes and lots of time reading the documentation :-)

Comment: Thank you Justin, Also from which version of Oracle, this atomic refresh feature can be applied

Comment: @shiv - As far as I can recall, atomic refreshes have been an option since materialized views existed back in 8i.  But I haven't gone back through two decade old documentation in a while so the specifics may well have been different in some early release.